# How to pass a control getting an ID from within a repeater to a href tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

in my asp usercontrol I have a repeater and inside that some basic controls that do some databindng.

One of these controls holds an id

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="itemsRepeater" OnItemDataBound="itemsRepeater_ItemDataBound">

<ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label  runat="server" ID="uId" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId") %>' />
    <a href="myLink and @UserId" runat="server">

</ItemTemplate>
```

How can I grab my label uId and pass its associated id to @UserId for each element in the repeater.

I have nothing in my OnItemDataBound event yet, I am moving to it now to find a work around to this.

Thanks.

**I fixed this by setting the databinder within the href**

```
<a id="link" runat="server" href='<%# "Details.aspx?userId=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId") %>'>
```

Comment: you can do it easily in jquery .

Answer (score 1):

A little modification in your code. I have just added a div around your Items.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="itemsRepeater" >
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div>
         <asp:Label id="uId" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId") %>' /></asp:Label>
         <a id="A1" runat="server">Click here</a>
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now your Js Code for adding uid to your link.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var yourlink = 'myurl';
    $('span[id^=itemsRepeater]').each(function (i) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('a').prop('href', yourlink + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: I have actually solved this issue using a different approach, just setting the databinder straight into the href with the correct syntax.
Thanks for the response though! In my OP is my fix.